# How do I say "I am going to Japan for a university exchange"?

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

I know exchange is 交換 in Japanese but is it right to say "大学交換”？

My current guess of the expression would be

> 日本に大学交換しに行きます。

Answer (score 1):

交換 is the correct word for "exchange", also in this context.

I think you could say

> 交換留学で日本に行きます。
>   I am going to Japan for a student/university exchange.